# How to remove Jupairdrop scam token from phantom wallet

Tags: token, jupiter, airdrop

How do you remove the scam tokens from your phantom wallet?

Comment: You can use a community tool called https://sol-incinerator.com

Answer (score -1):

you can go to "Sol Incinerator" to burn the scam token and scam NFT. Sometimes, you'll receive a reward in $SOL. After that, I suggest using "Wallet Guard" to secure your wallet, revoke the contract, perform a security analysis, and cancel any suspicious contracts. You can get information about my advice, but it's my personal procedure. Good luck!